# w3m displays inline images in konsole, but not yakuake

Tags: konsole, w3m

I've tested this on two different systems (with TERM set to `xterm-256color`) and got the same result. Nothing in the config files seems relevant.

Is there a major difference in these terminal emulators that I'm not aware of?

Also, is any thorough documentation available for either of them? They seem to come with no `man` pages. I found [the konsole handbook](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/applications/konsole/konsole.pdf), but it is very basic.

Comment: Does Yakuake set the `WINDOWID` environment variable?

Comment: W3m needs to know what window to draw on, and it uses the environment variable `WINDOWID` to determine that (or some heuristic that works less well). If you run a shell in Yakuake, does `echo $WINDOWID` show anything?

Comment: For what it's worth, yakuake sets `WINDOWID` to the same value that `xwininfo` finds.  But there is at least one different window, and while w3m sets aside space for images, they are not displayed.

Comment: This is an old question. Any chance for an update? Anyone got it working?